# Best method for including a large number of icons in a website?

Tags: css, fonts, svg, icons, sprite

I'm working on several web applications that all belong to the same site. Because there are several projects here I have a large number of icons that are needed, each to be available in about 12 different colors. (The reason for so many icons are very specific actions that require a specific custom icon). The total number of icons I'm working with easily reaches over 400 icons if you include all the color variations.

I had been using a css sprite image to include all these icons, but at this point as I keep having to add more icons, the CSS involved in generating these icons from the sprite is getting ridiculously long, and the sprite image become a lot larger.

Is there a better way I should be including these icons into the site? I've looked into making a icon font (they are all simple single color icons so this would be fine) but not sure how easy this is to update. I also thought about just making individual files for the icons as well and just include it as an image. And then there is the SVG route as well.

Based on how many icons I need, and that more icons are added reguarly, whcih do you think would be the best route to take for including the icons?

At most there might be up to 10 different icons per page, but unfortunately I can't guarantee that it would be 10 specific icons. (as in, there isn't a specific types of icons i can group together).

Thank you!

Comment: I recommend [Stitches](http://draeton.github.io/stitches/). I've used it to generate a spritesheet for FamFamFam and it works well. Updating your sheets would be easier, although you still have the issue of having to create the same spritesheet in different colours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give you some options, try having a look at [IcoMoon](http://icomoon.io/)

It's a web app that runs in Chrome and allows you to import your own SVG to create a custom icon font. It requires *some* tinkering, but I'd say not much more than generating a sprite sheet. You then have the flexibility that using an icon font gives you; resolution independence, easy colour amendments etc.

@Bojangles' suggestion of Stitches looks interesting; I'll have a tinker with that this afternoon! If you're on the Mac there's [SpriteRight](http://spriterightapp.com/), which is provides similar functionality if you prefer your apps native.

Comment: Thank you. IcoMoon looks interesting. I think an icon font would be best in my case and this seems to make it pretty easy. It's just too bad that it is hosted on their site and requires a subscription. Not sure my company will go for that.

Comment: Looks like I was wrong. Not sure what I was looking at but I see where I can do this for free now. Thanks again!